# WPF XAML Image Source and required windows authentication

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-authentication, imagesource

I want to display an image from an website requiring windows authentication. I'm currently using this:

```
<Image Grid.Column="0" Source="https://Foo/899fddb8-d5df-4f04-9d20-50de22f7d671/0102d4d6-3c3d-4717-985b-74021348413d.png" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
```

It works on browser and this code works :

```
<Image Grid.Column="0" Source="http://img.clubic.com/00C8009607654557-c1-photo-bbpppremium.jpg" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution :

In my App.config I put :

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true"  />
  </system.net>
```

In my App class :

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        Current.Startup += CurrentOnStartup;
    }

    private void CurrentOnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs startupEventArgs)
    {
        WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

        AuthenticationManager.CredentialPolicy = new ProxyCredentials();
    }
}

internal class ProxyCredentials : ICredentialPolicy
{
    bool ICredentialPolicy.ShouldSendCredential(Uri challengeUri, WebRequest request, NetworkCredential credential,
        IAuthenticationModule authenticationModule)

    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Source : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e5a064eb-578b-4334-95f6-e40d5a0e2cc2/proxy-authentication-problems-with-remote-resources-error-407?forum=wpf